# Error 13 - Type mismatch adding 2 columns together

Tags: excel, vba

I'm guessing I can't get away with this?

```
Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm).Range("H1:H50000").Value = Workbooks(ss).Sheets(cl).Range("I1:I50000").Value + Workbooks(ss).Sheets(cl).Range("J1:J50000").Value
```

Trying to get the new column to be the sum of the values in the other two. Why won't it let me?

Also, the below works just fine. It's just when I try adding 2 columns:

```
Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm).Range("A1:A50000").Value = Workbooks(ss).Sheets(cl).Range("M1:M50000").Value
```

Comment: In VBA, you need to process each row individually.

Comment: In this case OP doesn't need to process each row, but output a column.  Excel VBA can make use of Excel functions to handle this natively instead of looping through code 50,000 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to do an array somehow. I think the error is because while you can set `Range(A1:A10).Value` = `Range(B1:B10).Value`, trying to do `... = Range(B1:B10).Value + Range(C1:C10).Value`, VBA doesn't really understand what's happening...

Try looping through each cell instead:

```
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Workbooks(ss).Sheets(cl)
    For i = 1 To 50000
        Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm).Range("H" & i).Value = .Range("I" & i).Value + .Range("J" & i).Value
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Kind of lame I had to make a loop for it... VBA not advanced enough I guess :p

Comment: @dwirony - I just updated with a `WITH` statement to shorten it a little bit. Yeah, I am sure there's a more elegant way (like the formula suggested by @Scott below), but you'll need to add references to the workbook/worksheets too.  I just was lazy and did this, haha. You could *probably* even take Scott's a little further and use `EVALUATE` when doing it, removing the formulas all together in the sheet output.

Comment: Yes, you can use Evaluate to solve this: `myRange.Value = Evaluate("'[" & ss & "]" & cl & "'!I1:I50000 + '[" & ss & "]" & cl & "'!J1:J50000")` where myRange is set correctly

Answer (score 3):

Range.value is a Variant type, or basically an array.  What you're doing in your bottom example is copying one array (column A) into another array (column M).

However that array manipulation does not extend to doing arithmetic on the values inside the array, like what you expect to get from the first example.  So what's the best way to sum an array?

It turns out that even through you're programming in VBA, you have access to the full range of Excel functions, and Excel is remarkably good at doing math on ranges.  My recommended option is to set H as formulas like this:

```
Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm).Range("H1:H50000").Formula = "='[ss]cl'!I1+'[ss]cl'!J1"
```

If you want to then set the cells as values, add the 2nd line:

```
Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm).Range("H1:H50000").Value2 = Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm).Range("H1:H50000").Value2
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response Scott. I think the issue here is that since I'm grabbing my second values from another workbook, the formula wouldn't read correctly, would it?

Comment: For your first formula to work as-is, he would have to run this in the `Workbooks(ss).Sheets(cl)` workbook/sheet, yes?  Or would it be looking for the `I1` and `J1` in the `Workbooks(ms).Sheets(fm)` column, which could be empty.  If he/you add the workbook/sheet reference to the formula, that'd be better than looping for sure.  Or I could just be tired, and overlooking something.

Comment: @dwirony, I missed that it's another workbook, but still no problem! Excel formulas still work across workbooks, you just have to specify the source.  I'll edit my answer

Comment: Sorry about that Scott, I stole this snippet from my code without showing you what the variables were referencing. But yeah, if I was working out of one workbook this would work perfectly, but since I'm working across books it gave me a hard time...

Comment: Nice edit - does it work as is, or do you need to break out the formula to include the variable names, i.e. `"='[" & ss &"]" & cl & "'!I1+'[" & ss & "]" & cl & "'!J1"` (or something close to that, depending on how `ss` is labelled...?

Comment: In the example, I'm assuming that the worksheet is named "ss", but yes, if you want it to be a variable, what you're saying will work.  Up to you if you want to hardcode it or not.  Also, if you include the full path of the external workbook, you don't even have to have it open for this to work.